# Angular CDK:Getting error for FlexibleConnectedPositionStrategy in Overlay config

Tags: angular, angular-material, typescript2.0, angular-cdk

I want to configure an overlay for with overlay.position().flexibleConnectedTo() because connectedTo() is deprecated as per the [official docs](https://material.angular.io/cdk/overlay/api). 
Otherwise there is a [quesstion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47882427/how-to-add-a-position-strategy-to-an-overlay-angular-material) having a good answer for connectedTo()
[image]

**Here is my Code**

```
    const origin:FlexibleConnectedPositionStrategyOrigin=this.RefElem;
    const overlayConfig = new OverlayConfig();
    overlayConfig.positionStrategy = this.overlay.position().flexibleConnectedTo(origin);
    const overlayRef = this.overlay.create(overlayConfig);
    const userProfilePortal = new ComponentPortal(
      GraphMetaSignalSelectorComponent
    );
    overlayRef.attach(userProfilePortal);
```

but getting this error:
"ConnectedToFlexibleConnectedPositionStrategy: At least one position is required. at FlexibleConnectedPositionStrategy.push"

Comment: the only time I used Cdk is in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59199540/angular-cdk-attach-overlay-to-a-clicked-element/59272313#59272313, so I think that must be like `positionStrategy=this.overlay.position().flexibleConnectedTo(origin).withPositions(this.getPositions()).withPush(false)` -the function this.getPositions return an array of positions-

Comment: Thanks @Eliseo your answer is very helpful to play with Angular CDK

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For those curious who stuck with the accepted answer because of the lack of the implementation of `this.getPositions()`, here's a quick sample for copy-pasting:

```js
const positionStrategy = this.overlay.position()
      .flexibleConnectedTo(origin)
      .withPositions([{
        // here, top-left of the overlay is connected to bottom-left of the origin; 
        // of course, you can change this object or generate it dynamically;
        // moreover, you can specify multiple objects in this array for CDK to find the most suitable option
        originX: 'start',
        originY: 'bottom',
        overlayX: 'start',
        overlayY: 'top'
      } as ConnectedPosition])
      .withPush(false); // or true, if you want to push the overlay into the screen when it doesn't fit
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be like

```
positionStrategy=this.overlay.position().flexibleConnectedTo(origin)
                 .withPositions(this.getPositions()).withPush(false)
```

the function this.getPositions() return an array of positions
Note: Answer is based on a comment by @Eliseo which solved my problem

Comment: What is `this` in your context, and how are we supposed to have `this.getPositions()` method implemented?

Comment: Sorry, It's been 6 months, I left Angular. So, can't recall the whole context. But I think you don't have to implement getPositions method on your own. It's a built-in method that worked for me at that hard time.

Comment: I guess it returns the position of origin which is the reference for our Overlay Dialog